# Deleting object in If statement in Python

Tags: python

I have an array of objects in a JSON file. If a word in not in a value inside the object, I'd like to delete the entire object.

```
for x in results:
    if "Berline" in auction_type.split():
        if any(word in auction_model for word in berlinewords):
            del x
        else:
          pass
    else:
      pass
```

Doesn't work.

A sample of the database:

```
"objectID": 11460,
        "type": "Coupé",
        "cars_getroute": "bugatti-type-57-stelvio-cabriolet-1934-1936",
        "gm_url": "https://www.url.com",
        "results": [
            {
                "marque": "Bugatti",
                "model": "Type 57 Stelvio",
                "model_year": "1936",
                "price_str": "Estimate $900 000 - $1 200 000 (unsold)",
                "price_int": null,
                "price_currency": null,
                "sold": false,
                "auction_house": "RM Sotheby's",
                "auction_country": "USA",
                "auction_date": "12 mars 2016",
                "auction_datetime": "2016-03-12",
                "auction_url": null,
                "image_urls": "https://www.url.com",
                "price_int_eu": null
            }
        ]
```

If the Word "Berline" is in "type" and another in a list of other words in "model", I'd like to delete the object (just "results":[] in the example)

It is working well when I just try try to replace the value of model with a random one, but I can't delete the entire object.

Comment: Just FYI, if you have something like this, you don't need the `else: pass` every time.

Comment: you are changing something you are iterating over which will lead to all kinds of issues. (specifically with the `del x`)

Comment: "parent object" - parent to what? it seems unrelated to that check

Comment: I updated my question with a sample of the JSON trying to be more clear in my request.

Comment: `x` is just a local variable here.  Doing `del x` deletes only that variable (which will be recreated on the next iteration of the loop, anyway): it has absolutely no effect on the object being iterated over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate though a copy of `results`:

```
for o in results[:]:
    if <condition>:
        results.remove(o)
...
```